# Import CSV file with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have pretty big .csv file with data exported from one database (i'm not able to export it as anything else). And i try to import it to my mysql database.

But how ever i try I'm getting errors. First of all I don't have SSH on database server so I'm not able to change anything on apache site , for PHP my admin is file too big, if i try to use LOAD DATA INFILE I'm importing blanked rows.

Is there a chance somebody can help me with that?

CSV file example:

```
"Manufacturer","Main Type","Option Code","Option Description 1"
"JD" "50" "A1" "OD POČÁTKU VÝROBY"
"JD" "50" "A2" "OD VIN 340001"
"JD" "50" "A3" "OD VIN 440000"
"JD" "50" "A4" "OD VIN 440001"
```

Only possible option which work for me a bit:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'solic2.txt' INTO TABLE solic_code FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

p.s. I was able to do that in my localhost via HeidySql but as soon as server have blocked ports I'm not able to do the same for server site..

Comment: did you try to load file with just 1 record? what is error message?

Comment: I am just trying to test it with 4 records instead of all data, importing blanked columns :(

Comment: why "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' "; we can see that your fields are separated/terminated by ","

Comment: I tryed both , edit .txt then edit sql command just to find a way how Mysql will understand it. I unfortunately post code when termiante with t and old csv file.

I am sorry for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'solic2.txt' INTO TABLE solic_code FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This is a csv (comma separated) rather than tab separated, which is what you set with \t.

To make sure it will be using UTF-8:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'solic2.txt' INTO TABLE solic_code  CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: It's actually pretty good, it add things to correct column. But there is a small problems.
1. It import just 80k lines instead of 160k 
2. in last column it add " - for example OD VIN 340001"
"JD

Comment: I failed, look's it have problem with file format, after changed on UTF-8 it working.  THANK YOU!

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'solic_unchanged.txt' INTO TABLE solic_code FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: Glad it worked. I was just checking the mysql manual and was thinking it might be a stray character, but being the wrong char-set would explain it too.

Comment: I am trying to use same way as suggested it only inserted 2 rows instead the csv file have 1 million rows.

Comment: <?php 
include '../class/pdo.php'; 
$pdo = new PDO();
$pdo_connection = $pdo->pdo_connect();
$tt="1cs2cs1cs17409061651452795086two.csv";
$aa=",";
$bb='"';
$cc='\n';
echo $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$tt."' INTO TABLE data2  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$aa."'  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".$bb."' LINES TERMINATED BY '".$cc."' IGNORE 1 LINES;";
$queryresource = $pdo_connection->query($query);
?>

Comment: #abhinavBruteForce - The LINES TERMINATED BY setting may be wrong. Some windows files might need a \r (carriage return) added. If that does not work you`ll have to carefully inspect the data file, using a hex viewer or some such, to see what characters it is using. Alternatively it may not be a UTF-8 file so try it without the UFT8 setting or with some other character set (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html)